# Next js : Is it good to pass hooks as arguments in a function present in another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if is was good practice to send consts from hooks as arguments to a helper function in another file , so that these hooks can be used there .

Will it cause any problems , or is better to have the helper function in index.js itself ? so that there is no need to pass the arguments

My index.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { helperFunc } from "./helpers.js"

const App = () => {

const [name, setName] = useState("")
const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
const router = useRouter()

 


return (
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => helperFunc(name, setName, page, setPage, router)}>Test</button>
     .......
   </div>

   
)

}
```

My helpers.js

```
export const helperFunc = (name, setName, page, setPage, router) => {
  // have logic that uses the arguments 
  if (name === "test") {
    router.push("/test")
    setName("")
  }

}
```

Comment: It's fine as you're not passing hooks, you're passing callbacks meant to be passed around. If it's good though depends on the actual use-case and implementation, which is likely opinion based.

Comment: It would be a good idea if a custom hook would return some data that would later be processed in a separate function.